# timeout doesn't work with accumulo shell in bash script

Tags: shell-script, timeout

I'm trying to check if a scan of an Accumulo table times out (to see if the table is corrupted).

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout -s KILL 20s accumulo shell -zi myInstance -u root -p secret -e "scan -np -t myTable"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 'Scan successful'
else
  echo 'Scan timed out'
fi
```

The script runs the full 20 seconds and doesn't execute the `accumulo shell` command<s>, and also returns a 0 exit status incorrectly</s>.

If I run the above timeout command in a terminal the command runs as expected. 
If I run a basic timeout command (e.g. `timeout -s KILL 20s sleep 10`) in the script or in a terminal, that works as well. So for some reason the combination of a timeout and `accumulo shell` command in a bash script does not work.

- Accumulo version: 1.6.0-cdh4.6.0
- OS version: CentOS 6.6

Comment: Does the shell command work without the timeout?

Comment: Yes, the shell command works without the timeout in both the script and terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue stems from running the command in a different shell. If I run the script using the `source` command, e.g. `source myScript.sh`, the script runs as expected.

However, I haven't yet been able to track down *why* running the combination of `timeout` and `accummulo shell` in a different shell doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the way the accumulo script calls exec to launch Java?